# What font is used on the "Passengers" movie poster?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

This is the poster in question:

[image]

And here is a close-up of the font I'd like to know:

[image]

I would like to know what font is used here. Most font recognition engines can't see the "E" without the "Vertical Line" so it's hard for them to identify the font. I've also searched around for similar futuristic fonts but most of them have "curved edges", for example:

[[image: ]]
Click for full version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k6D5.png)

Comment: I've just noticed this is very similar to the font used by easyJet, for example in https://untilsundaypost.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/easyjet_font.png

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This probably is a custom type based on some different fonts. The basis seems to be [Neutraface N°2 Medium](https://houseind.com/hi/neutraface_no2) and/or [Aramis Light or SemiLight](http://www.fontbros.com/families/aramis/styles/bold?u=whatfontis).

Inspiration also seems to be taken from [Revival](http://www.revivaltype.com) and maybe even good old  [Futura](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/futura/).

Someone took the time to recreate the font though, you can find it [here](http://www.fontspace.com/fz/pasajero).

Comment: Thank You very much! That's just what I was looking for!

Comment: Cheers! Have fun creating! And feel free to hang around to contribute to the site and help us make it a great resource for all lovers of graphic design.

Answer (score 10):

You can get a similar effect with most fonts by using a Greek capital lambda and xi, as in:

PΛSSΞNGΞRS

I know it's not entirely what you're asking for but you might be able to get a similar effect, if it's the effect rather than the typeface itself you want.

Comment: Nice. Though, this is similar to "Яussianizing", or  abuse of the Cyrillic letter Я that probably annoys anyone who knows that Я is pronounced "Ya". Though in this case you're not trying to be indicative of Greece so it's probably not that bad :)

Comment: @WayneWerner there might be an element of that, but I think that there's a distinction between this and what I would say was the Greek equivalent of Russianising, using Σ instead of E and Ω instead of O and the like (coming up with things like "APHRΩΔITΣ" for "APHRODITE") - the idea here is just the shape of the glyph rather than attempting to make something look generically Slavic or generically Greek...

Comment: It may be worth noting that this may be problematic in computerized contexts—for example, if you used that on a website (like that, not in an image), a screen reader (non-visual browser for the blind) is almost certainly going to read it out as "Pee Lambda Ess Ess Xi Enn Gee Xi Arr Ess" and not "passengers."

Comment: @KRyan this is a concern, and one I hadn't thought of - would something like <span aria-label="passengers">PΛSSΞNGΞRS</span> solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the typeface *Revival* (http://www.revivaltype.com/) is not the font used (the G is quite different) it is certainly similar enough (including the very unusual "A" and "E") that it might well be of interest to you.

In my opinion the title here is modified Futura, this image :https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOlv7.jpg shows Futura modified into this mark.

Answer (score 0):

Montserrat Light Alt1 - found it on befonts